# Crosspost prevention

Tags: discussion

Say one realizes in hindsight that a question better fits another Stackexchange. How to close the one here to avoid cross-posting effects? Or.. is there another - better - route to take?

Comment: As the author you can just delete the question, if you are not the OP you can vote to close it as a duplicate.

Comment: Ditto -- the catch would be if you've posted something and it has answers with upvotes, meaning you can't delete the question anymore.  In that case you could vote to close your own question and/or ping a moderator in chat to ask them to do it.  BTW I think your stuff about Debian security update nomenclature would be much better off on U&L, and if you don't get anywhere with that try a Debian mailing list -- it is certainly obscure to the point of obtuse.  By which I mean them not you ;)

Comment: *"better off on U&L"* -> Than here, not necessarily better than infosec.SE.

Comment: Thanks! I deleted one of my posts here in favor of keeping my post at [Information Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/137930/how-do-cve-patched-package-versions-relate/137956?noredirect=1#comment257601_137956).

Comment: @goldilocks "By which I mean them not you" You sure? I can get.. err kinda verbal.. T.B.F. ^^

Answer (score 1):

**Delete post**

As the 'original poster' (OP) one can simply delete the question using the 'delete' link in its bottom-row moderation/modification menu. - Thanks @Steve Robillard for pointing that out (I should have found that myself.. t.b.f.)!

**Downvote post**

This does not work when external's have placed their footprint on it (such as up/down votes. In that case one could simply downvote one's own question (however I suspect that does not look good on one's StackExchange resume though ^^). - Thanks @goldilocks for pointing it out!

**Chat a moderator**

A moderator chat/request would do the trick too. - Thanks again @goldilocks!

Comment: You can't vote for your own posts and I don't know why goldilocks would suggest such a thing. Ok, you can vote for close (that is what goldi said) but you cannot up/down vote it.

Comment: @Ghanima Because you can vote *to close* your own question if you cannot delete it (and you cannot delete it if it has upvoted answers).